# How to fix "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing." in discord python

Tags: discord.py

How to fix the error, but at the same time the class and self should remain?

Here Are the TraceBack:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
> > await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> > File "C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
> > await self.prepare(ctx)
> > File "C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
> > await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
> > File "C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
> > transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
> > File "C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
> > raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
> > discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

And here are the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import inspect


class StarBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self, command_prefix, **options):
        super().__init__(command_prefix, **options)
        members = inspect.getmembers(self)
        for name, member in members:
            if isinstance(member, commands.Command):
                if member.parent is None:
                    self.add_command(member)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    @commands.command(name='reg', help='Для регистрации', pass_context=True)
    async def reg(self, ctx):
        if ' '.join(str(ctx.channel).split(' ')[:2]) == 'Direct Message':
            await self.embed(ctx.channel, "Начало регистрации")


    async def embed_channel(self, channel, title, string='', color=0xff9900):
        embed = discord.Embed(color=color, title=title, description=string)
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

        return msg

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = StarBot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Could you try without `name='reg'` and without `pass_context=True` ? Those already have those values by default. You could also try *typing* the ctx variable by doing `self, ctx: Context`, maybe it will work better

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code here:

```
    @commands.command(name='reg', help='Для регистрации', pass_context=True)
    async def reg(self, ctx):
        if ' '.join(str(ctx.channel).split(' ')[:2]) == 'Direct Message':
            await self.embed(ctx.channel, "Начало регистрации")
```

Here, you have (self,ctx):

```
    async def reg(self, ctx):
```

In a cog it needs to be (client,ctx):

```
    async def reg(client, ctx):
```

It should look like:

```
    @commands.command(name='reg', help='Для регистрации', pass_context=True)
    async def reg(client, ctx):
        if ' '.join(str(ctx.channel).split(' ')[:2]) == 'Direct Message':
            await self.embed(ctx.channel, "Начало регистрации")
```